# No mapping found for the http request with URI [] in dispacher servlet (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, dispatcher

I am trying to run basic spring mvc application using annotations and getting the following error.

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/testSpring/hello1.htm] in
DispatcherServlet with name 'testSpring'
I have searched a lot and evreything looks fine.

I am adding my web.xml, servlet.xml and controller file.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testSpring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/testSpring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testSpring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.jsp
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

testSpring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
    <!-- the application context definition for the testSpring DispatcherServlet -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.testSpring.web" />
    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!--<bean name="/hello.htm" class="HelloController"/>-->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

HelloAnnotController.java

```
package com.testSpring.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello1")
public class HelloAnnotController {
//
//    @RequestMapping("/my/hello1")
    public ModelAndView visitHome() {
        return  new ModelAndView("hello1");

    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<c:redirect url="/hello1.htm"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `@RequestMapping("/hello1.htm")`?

Comment: yes i have tried with @RequestMapping("/hello1.htm") also. It gives the same error.

Comment: You're lacking a RequestMapping annotation on the method. And you're using the ModelAndView class from the wrong package (porlet instead of servlet).

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBNizet. Adding the request mapping to the method worked and removing it from the controller worked. :)